# Python: Matching space with a If statement

Tags: python, string, if-statement

Hi I have an script that look for information and the information is suppose to be integers, but sometime I find a empty string and because of that I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I was trying to do the following, but it does not work.

```
list = ['12', '14', '45', ''] 

for i in list:
    if '' in i:
        i = 0
        i
    else:
        i
```

This will match everything. It got to be another way and there is no way I can edit the source. Thanks

Comment: You can't edit the source code, or the data source? Also, what are you doing with this data, are you storing it back into the list, or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm putting in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `list` as a variable name. Sooner or later you will want to use the builting `list` and get strange bugs :)

```
my_list = ['12', '14', '45', ''] 

for i in my_list:
    if not i:
        # i is empty string
    else:
        # ...
```

I guess the error you have shown is from elsewhere where you are trying to use `int(i)`

If `i` is supposed to be converted to an `int`, one way to do it is like this

```
for i in my_list:
    if not i:
        i = 0
    else:
        i = int(i)
```

Another way is to use an exception handler

```
for i in my_list:
    try:
        i = int(i)
    except ValueError:
        i = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple but effective way is to catch that error and ignore it. You can also check for "truthiness" of the value.

```
mylist = ['12', '14', '45', '']
outlist = []

for s in mylist:
    if s:
        try:
            i = int(s)
        except ValueError:
            continue

        else:
            outlist.append(i)
```

This also protects you from other types of non-numeric input.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will take all elements in your list and filter out the ones that are blank.

```
mylist =  ['1','2','3','4','','','6','7']

for x in mylist:
    if x:
        print x
    else:
        pass # x is empty
```

your method is probably failing because you are using `in` instead of `is`.

Also, don't name your list `list` as that is overriding the `list` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want this:

```
for i in lst:
    if i == "":
        i = 0
    else:
        i = int(i)

    # do stuff with an iteger i here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe looking for something like

```
import string
list = ['12', '14', '45', '', '1 3']

for i in list:
    if i == '':
        i = 0
        print i
    elif ' ' in i:
        i = string.replace(i, ' ', '')
        print i
    else:
        print i
```